# Issues in implementing long drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am pretty new to programming and I am trying to implement a solution for long dropdown menus, created by Chris at CSS-tricks. However having no luck in doing. Here is my code.

```
li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-cart{
min-width:350px;
display:block;
}
li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-cart li .item{

display:block;
min-width:350px;
padding:3px 10px;
margin: 3px 0;

}
ul.dropdown-cart li .item:hover{
min-width:350px;
background-color:#f3f3f3;
}
ul.dropdown-cart li .item:after{
min-width:350px;
visibility: hidden;
display: block;
font-size: 0;
content: " ";
clear: both;
height: 0;
}


ul.dropdown-cart li .item-left{

float:left;
}
ul.dropdown-cart li .item-left img,
ul.dropdown-cart li .item-left span.item-info{
float:left;


}
ul.dropdown-cart li .item-left span.item-info{

margin-left:10px;
}
ul.dropdown-cart li .item-left span.item-info span{

display:block;
}
ul.dropdown-cart li .item-right{

float:right;
}
ul.dropdown-cart li .item-right button{

margin-top:14px;
}
ul.dropdown-cart li .item-right1{
text-align: right;

}
```

Here is my HTML

```
    <ul style="list-style-type:none">
        <div class="cart box_1">
            <a href="checkout.html">
    <a href="cart.php"><li class="dropdown" > <img src="images/cart.png" alt="" style="padding-top: 6px"/> <div class="numberCircle"><?=$item_count?></div></a>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-cart dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
                        <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a class="text-center" style="font-weight: bold;">Cart is empty!</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is the implemented js code

```
var maxHeight = 400;

$(function(){

    $(".dropdown-cart > li").hover(function() {

         var $container = $(this),
             $list = $container.find("ul"),
             $anchor = $container.find("a"),
             height = $list.height() * 1.1,       // make sure there is enough room at the bottom
             multiplier = height / maxHeight;     // needs to move faster if list is taller

        // need to save height here so it can revert on mouseout
        $container.data("origHeight", $container.height());

        // so it can retain it's rollover color all the while the dropdown is open
        $anchor.addClass("hover");

        // make sure dropdown appears directly below parent list item
        $list
            .show()
            .css({
                paddingTop: $container.data("origHeight")
            });

        // don't do any animation if list shorter than max
        if (multiplier > 1) {
            $container
                .css({
                    height: maxHeight,
                    overflow: "hidden"
                })
                .mousemove(function(e) {
                    var offset = $container.offset();
                    var relativeY = ((e.pageY - offset.top) * multiplier) - ($container.data("origHeight") * multiplier);
                    if (relativeY > $container.data("origHeight")) {
                        $list.css("top", -relativeY + $container.data("origHeight"));
                    };
                });
        }

    }, function() {

        var $el = $(this);

        // put things back to normal
        $el
            .height($(this).data("origHeight"))
            .find("ul")
            .css({ top: 0 })
            .hide()
            .end()
            .find("a")
            .removeClass("hover");

    });

});
```

Comment: Can you share link for what you are trying to implement? Also, what is the exact issue faced by you?

Comment: Essentially I have a page where useres can add items to their cart, and i also have a dropdown menu where the user can see all the items they have added to the cart. However, i would not like the items to scroll down to the page. The effect I am trying to achieving can be seen here: https://codepen.io/larrygeams/pen/feoDc